# Is it possible to change the FLV's frame rate programmatically?

Tags: actionscript-3, flv

I have tried with stage.framerate but It doesn't seem to work. Is there a way to adjust the FLV's framerate at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flash player always renders video at the video's native framerate (resources permitting), regardless of the framerate it's playing flash content at (which is why changing [Stage.frameRate](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/display/Stage.html#frameRate) doesn't affect video. So if you're aiming for something like slow-motion or fast-forward playback, there's no direct way to do this without manually advancing the video position at the speed you want.